# Is there any possibility to invert a symmetric banded (7 diagonals) matrix in linear time?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse, symmetric

I need to invert a p x p symmetric banded hessian matrix H, which has 7 diagonals. p may be very high (=1000 or 10000).

H^{-1} can be considered as banded, and thus, I do not need to compute the complete inverse matrix, but rather its approximation. (It could be assumed to have 11 or 13 diagonals for example.)
I am looking for a method which does not imply parallelization.

Is there any possibility to build such an algorithm with R, in linear time?

Comment: If something like this is available, I expect it in package Matrix. E.g., there: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/solve-methods.html. Of course, matrix inversion should usually be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

There is no linear time algorithm for this, to the best of my knowledge. 
But you're not totally without hope:

1. Your matrix is not really that large, so using a relatively optimised implementation might be reasonably fast for `p < 10K`. For example a *dense* LU decomposition requires at most `O(p^3)`, with p = 1000, that would probably take less than a second. In practice, an implementation for sparse matrices should achieve much better performance, taking advantage of the sparsity;
2. Do you really, really, *really* need to compute the inverse? Very often explicitly computing the inverse can be replaced by solving an equivalent linear system; with some methods such as iterative solvers (e.g. [conjugate gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)) solving the linear system is significantly more efficient because the sparsity pattern of the source matrix is preserved, leading to reduced work; when computing the inverse, even if you do know it's OK to approximate with a banded matrix, there will still be substantial amount of fill-in (added nonzero values)

Putting it all together I'd suggest you try out the [R matrix package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/solve-methods.html) for your matrix. Try all available signatures and ensure you have a high performance BLAS implementation installed. Also try to rewrite your call to compute the inverse:

```
# e.g. rewrite...
A_inverse = solve(A)
x = y * A_inverse
# ... as
x = solve(A, y)
```

This may be more subtle for your purposes, but there is a very high chance you should be able to do it, as suggested in the package docs:

```
 solve(a, b, ...) ## *the* two-argument version, almost always preferred to
 solve(a)         ## the *rarely* needed one-argument version
```

If all else fails, you may have to try more efficient implementations available in: [Matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), [Suite Sparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html), [PetSC](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/471374).